# Install CYGWIN x86-64 on wine

Tags: ubuntu, cygwin, wine, general-network-error

I tried to install cygwin x86-64 on my Ubuntu 20.04 system with wine64 (5.5). Althouth that sounds strange I need it for development and debugging. But the install procedure leads to an error:

```sh
$ WINEPREFIX=~/cygwin/ WINEARCH=win64 wine64 ../setup-x86_64.exe 
Starting cygwin install, version 2.917
User has backup/restore rights
LookupPrivilegeValue() failed: 1313
User has NO symlink creation right
0009:fixme:ntdll:NtSetInformationToken unimplemented class 4
SetTokenInformation(owner)() failed: 1
io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
Current Directory: Z:\home\koehlerm\Downloads
source: network install
root: C:\cygwin64 system
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(C:\cygwin64/var/log, group) failed: 1337
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(C:\cygwin64/var, group) failed: 1337
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(C:\cygwin64, group) failed: 1337
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(C:\cygwin64/var, group) failed: 1337
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(C:\cygwin64/var/log, group) failed: 1337
Selected local directory: Z:\home\koehlerm\Downloads
net: Preconfig
002b:fixme:thread:GetThreadUILanguage : stub, returning default language.
002b:fixme:wininet:InternetAttemptConnect Stub
002b:fixme:thread:GetThreadUILanguage : stub, returning default language.
LookupPrivilegeValue() failed: 1313
connection error: 12006 fetching https://cygwin.com/mirrors.lst
002b:fixme:wininet:query_global_option Stub for 9
mbox note: Could not download mirror sites list
mbox : Are you sure you want to exit setup? Any current download or installation will be aborted.
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(, group) failed: 1337
io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/setup.rc) failed 2 No such file or directory
Ending cygwin install
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(, group) failed: 1337
AddAccessAllowedAceEx(, group) failed: 1337
```

If I specify a mirror manually, the files from that mirror cannot be downloaded as well.